Two values of Rydberg Constant
In my textbook I came across two values of Rydberg Constant:
\begin{align}
R&= 109\,677\ \mathrm{cm}^{-1}
\\
R_h&= 2.18 × 10^{-18}\ \mathrm J 
\end{align}
when we are calculating energy of the stationary state.
So can anyone clear this confusion of mine?

In most sources I'm familiar with, the first one is the "Rydberg constant" while the second one is called the "Rydberg energy" to differentiate it.

The Rydberg constant can be expressed in two different units depending on the context and what quantity it is being used to calculate:

$\mathrm{R = 109677~cm^{-1}}$. This value is used when calculating wavenumbers (1/wavelength) of photons emitted or absorbed during electron transitions in hydrogen-like atoms using the Rydberg formula:

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} = R\left(\frac{1}{n_1^2} - \frac{1}{n_2^2}\right)$$
Where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the principal quantum numbers of the initial and final states. The units work out to be ${cm^{-1}}$ (or ${m^{-1}}$).

$\mathrm{R_h = 2.18 × 10^{-18}~J}$. This is the Rydberg unit of energy and represents the ionization energy of the hydrogen atom in the ground state. It is used when calculating the energy levels of hydrogen-like atoms:

$$E_n = -\frac{R_h}{n^2}$$
Where n is the principal quantum number. The negative sign indicates the electron is bound to the nucleus.
The two values are related by:
$$R_h = hcR$$
Where h is Planck's constant and c is the speed of light. Multiplying the value in ${cm^{-1}}$ by $hc$ converts it to units of energy (J).
Use $\mathrm{R = 109677~cm^{-1}}$ when working with the Rydberg formula and dealing with wavelengths/wavenumbers of transitions. Use $\mathrm{R_h = 2.18 × 10^{-18}~J}$ when calculating energy levels directly. The constant is the same, just expressed in different units for different purposes. Let me know if this clears up the confusion!
